# Is Fingerprint Scanner TTL (GT-511C3) compatible with Raspberry Pi Zero?

Tags: gpio, pi-zero, uart

I have a question regarding Fingerprint Scanner - TTL (GT-511C3).
Here is a [link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BFH29GK).

Is this fingerprint scanner compatible with Raspberry Pi Zero?

Answer (score 5):

This Fingerprint Scanner is compatible with the Raspberry Pi Zero. As it uses `UART` to interface.

Amazon.com says the fingerprint scanner uses, "*Simple UART protocol (Default 9600 baud)*".
Since the Raspberry Pi Zero does have `UART` pins it is compatible.

**Note**: this fingerprint scanner is also compatible with all other versions of Raspberry Pi, as they all come standard with `UART` pins.

Here is a [tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-zero-creation/enable-uart) on getting started using `UART` on the Raspberry Pi Zero.